String interpolation with LocalizedStringKey
I use string catalog and I'm trying to make LocalizedStringKey interpolatable such as:
"\(a.localizedString()) · \(b.localizedString())"

I have localizedString implemented like this:
enum A {
  case a1
  case a2

  func localizedString() -> LocalizedStringKey {
    return "aa"
  }
}

However, it doesn't display the correct value but show string literals like "LocalizedStringKey(key: ...)". My question is how I should do the right string interpolation with LocalizedStringKey?

Does this answer your question? See also this which is also related.

@Sweeper i don't see how they work for my case. please don't close my questions if you aren't sure

You should [edit] your question to explain why the duplicate target doesn't answer your question. Show what you tried from that post, and how it didn't work.

@Sweeper no it isn't a duplicate target. you can't just find a misleading one and ask  op to explain why it doesn't work or close their questions. there're tons of seemingly related questions here. it's your job to understand the differences if you really want to suggest an action.

It isn't clear what you're trying to do. LocalizedStringKey is not a defined type, so your code won't compile without your definition of it. Your function looks like it returns a static, non-localized String, so how is your code actually useful?

If you edit your question to explain what you are trying to do, and how that is different than all the other questions and answers on localizing strings, we can re-open it and help you, but as of now, I don't understand what you are trying to do.

@DuncanC what i'm trying to do is quite self-explanatory. LocalizedStringKey is a well-known native struct. if you don't even get what it is i really can't help you understand more. it's ok if you don't reopen the question. it's just so hilarious that experts here don't even know common structs and simple code

Do you mean something like this?
extension LocalizedStringKey {
var value: String {
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
if let val = mirror.children.first(where: { $0.label == "key" })?.value as? String {
return NSLocalizedString(val, comment: "")
}
return ""
}
}
enum A {
case a1
case a2
func localizedString() -> String {
return LocalizedStringKey("aa").value
}
}
